# Google Chrome silently crashing on Windows 8

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8

I have recently picked up a new Dell Vostro (64 bit) running Windows 8 Professional.

I have installed Google Chrome on it however it seems to silently crash each time it runs. The error log below is what seems to be reported on each occasions but it gives me little to nothing to go on.

```
    The program chrome.exe version 23.0.1271.97 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Action Center control panel.
 Process ID: 162c
 Start Time: 01cde36415ef2c4c
 Termination Time: 33
 Application Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
 Report Id: 35d2af11-4f59-11e2-be6f-08edb948381a
 Faulting package full name: 
 Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I also see Microsoft Error reporting kicking in just prior to this crash with the following error message

```
    <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Windows Error Reporting" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1001</EventID> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-12-26T12:38:57.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>1506</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>CS-DEV-DG.coopersoftware.local</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>50</Data> 
  <Data>5</Data> 
  <Data>AppHangB1</Data> 
  <Data>Not available</Data> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>chrome.exe</Data> 
  <Data>23.0.1271.97</Data> 
  <Data>50be88d8</Data> 
  <Data>01b3</Data> 
  <Data>133120</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Local\Temp\WER3A60.tmp.appcompat.txt C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Local\Temp\WER3A9F.tmp.version.xml C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Local\Temp\WER3AB0.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml</Data> 
  <Data>C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\Critical_chrome.exe_351ac63943b3fadc1a9bcda2dae6a793d347758_08333ea6</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>35d2af11-4f59-11e2-be6f-08edb948381a</Data> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>ed03c2854bd3816327a2f2cda34099e0</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

EDIT: Process Monitor only gives the followinf for the wait chain analysis

[image: Process Monitor Output]

Comment: chrome hasn't crashed, it simply hangs. restart Chrome without any extensions and without HW acceleration.

Comment: there are no extensions and Hardware acceleration is turned off. It is certainly crashing as it closes all windows and then asks to restore tabs on next load

Comment: when you have the issue again, use resource Monitor to see why Chrome hangs: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2009/04/18/wait-chain-traversal-in-windows-7-resource-monitor.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you know....those lovely chaps at Google have identified the issue...which looks like it related to some bug in bookmark syncing

See the following response from the chaps at Chromium which seems to have resolved my issue!!!

```
Chrome Version: 23.0.1271.97
Operating System: e.g., Windows 8 Professional 

URL (if applicable) where crash occurred:

This bug/crash happens every time I am using Google Chrome on Windows 8 (In both desktop mode and Metro mode) 


I have recently picked up a new Dell Vostro (64 bit) running Windows 8 Professional.

I have installed Google Chrome on it however it seems to silently crash each time it runs. The error log below is what seems to be reported on each occasions but it gives me little to nothing to go on.

    The program chrome.exe version 23.0.1271.97 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Action Center control panel.
 Process ID: 162c
 Start Time: 01cde36415ef2c4c
 Termination Time: 33
 Application Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
 Report Id: 35d2af11-4f59-11e2-be6f-08edb948381a
 Faulting package full name: 
 Faulting package-relative application ID: 

I also see Microsoft Error reporting kicking in just prior to this crash with the following error message

    <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Windows Error Reporting" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1001</EventID> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-12-26T12:38:57.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>1506</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>CS-DEV-DG.coopersoftware.local</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>50</Data> 
  <Data>5</Data> 
  <Data>AppHangB1</Data> 
  <Data>Not available</Data> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>chrome.exe</Data> 
  <Data>23.0.1271.97</Data> 
  <Data>50be88d8</Data> 
  <Data>01b3</Data> 
  <Data>133120</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Local\Temp\WER3A60.tmp.appcompat.txt C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Local\Temp\WER3A9F.tmp.version.xml C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Local\Temp\WER3AB0.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml</Data> 
  <Data>C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\Critical_chrome.exe_351ac63943b3fadc1a9bcda2dae6a793d347758_08333ea6</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>0</Data> 


*Please note that issues filed with no information filled in above will be marked as WontFix*

****DO NOT CHANGE BELOW THIS LINE****
report_id:21a38294612244c3
Comment 1 by asvitkine@chromium.org, Jan 2 (6 days ago)
Seems to be related to bookmark sync:

0x5bd8afd5   [chrome.dll]    - xtree:63]    std::_Tree_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<policy::ConfigurationPolicyProvider *,std::less<policy::ConfigurationPolicyProvider *>,std::allocator<policy::ConfigurationPolicyProvider *>,0> >,std::_Iterator_base0>::operator++()
0x5c256120   [chrome.dll]    - algorithm:40]    std::_Find<std::_Tree_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<BookmarkNode const *,std::less<BookmarkNode const *>,std::allocator<BookmarkNode const *>,0> >,std::_Iterator_base0>,BookmarkNode const *>(std::_Tree_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<BookmarkNode const *,std::less<BookmarkNode const *>,std::allocator<BookmarkNode const *>,0> >,std::_Iterator_base0>,std::_Tree_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<BookmarkNode const *,std::less<BookmarkNode const *>,std::allocator<BookmarkNode const *>,0> >,std::_Iterator_base0>,BookmarkNode const * const &)
0x5cceab3a   [chrome.dll]    - bookmark_index.cc:257]   BookmarkIndex::RegisterNode(std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &,BookmarkNode const *)
0x5cceae58   [chrome.dll]    - bookmark_index.cc:66]    BookmarkIndex::Add(BookmarkNode const *)
0x5cc792c4   [chrome.dll]    - bookmark_model.cc:714]   BookmarkModel::AddNode(BookmarkNode *,int,BookmarkNode *,bool)
0x5cc79711   [chrome.dll]    - bookmark_model.cc:486]   BookmarkModel::AddURLWithCreationTime(BookmarkNode const *,int,std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &,GURL const &,base::Time const &)
0x5cc79989   [chrome.dll]    - bookmark_model.cc:456]   BookmarkModel::AddURL(BookmarkNode const *,int,std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &,GURL const &)
0x5cc97624   [chrome.dll]    - bookmark_change_processor.cc:602]    browser_sync::BookmarkChangeProcessor::CreateBookmarkNode(syncer::BaseNode *,BookmarkNode const *,BookmarkModel *,int)
0x5cc99c02   [chrome.dll]    - bookmark_model_associator.cc:484]    browser_sync::BookmarkModelAssociator::BuildAssociations()
0x5cc9a600   [chrome.dll]    - bookmark_model_associator.cc:369]    browser_sync::BookmarkModelAssociator::AssociateModels()
0x5cc91f0d   [chrome.dll]    - frontend_data_type_controller.cc:178]    browser_sync::FrontendDataTypeController::Associate()
0x5cc91dff   [chrome.dll]    - frontend_data_type_controller.cc:84] browser_sync::FrontendDataTypeController::StartAssociating(base::Callback<void (browser_sync::DataTypeController::StartResult,syncer::SyncError const &)> const &)
0x5ccff87d   [chrome.dll]    - model_association_manager.cc:452]    browser_sync::ModelAssociationManager::StartAssociatingNextType()
0x5ccfeb44   [chrome.dll]    - model_association_manager.cc:407]    browser_sync::ModelAssociationManager::ModelLoadCallback(syncer::ModelType,syncer::SyncError)
0x5ccfe960   [chrome.dll]    - bind_internal.h:940] base::internal::InvokeHelper<1,void,base::internal::RunnableAdapter<void ( browser_sync::ModelAssociationManager::*)(syncer::ModelType,syncer::SyncError)>,void (base::WeakPtr<browser_sync::ModelAssociationManager> const &,syncer::ModelType const &,syncer::SyncError const &)>::MakeItSo(base::internal::RunnableAdapter<void ( browser_sync::ModelAssociationManager::*)(syncer::ModelType,syncer::SyncError)>,base::WeakPtr<browser_sync::ModelAssociationManager> const &,syncer::ModelType const &,syncer::SyncError const &)
0x5ccfe97b   [chrome.dll]    - bind_internal.h:1319]    base::internal::Invoker<1,base::internal::BindState<base::internal::RunnableAdapter<void ( browser_sync::ModelAssociationManager::*)(syncer::ModelType,syncer::SyncError)>,void (browser_sync::ModelAssociationManager *,syncer::ModelType,syncer::SyncError),void (base::WeakPtr<browser_sync::ModelAssociationManager>)>,void (browser_sync::ModelAssociationManager *,syncer::ModelType,syncer::SyncError)>::Run(base::internal::BindStateBase *,syncer::ModelType const &,syncer::SyncError const &)
0x5cc91db0   [chrome.dll]    - frontend_data_type_controller.cc:72] browser_sync::UIDataTypeController::OnModelLoaded()
0x5cc90bd3   [chrome.dll]    - frontend_data_type_controller.cc:61] browser_sync::FrontendDataTypeController::LoadModels(base::Callback<void (syncer::ModelType,syncer::SyncError)> const &)
0x5ccff3f7   [chrome.dll]    - model_association_manager.cc:362]    browser_sync::ModelAssociationManager::LoadModelForNextType()
0x5ccff45b   [chrome.dll]    - model_association_manager.cc:161]    browser_sync::ModelAssociationManager::StartAssociationAsync()
0x5cc943d0   [chrome.dll]    - data_type_manager_impl.cc:192]   browser_sync::DataTypeManagerImpl::DownloadReady(syncer::EnumSet<syncer::ModelType,2,16>)

Labels: Feature-Sync Feature-Bookmarks 
Comment 2 by zea@chromium.org, Jan 2 (6 days ago)
About how many synced bookmarks would you say you have? You can check on google.com/dashboard under the sync section if you don't remember.

If you disable bookmark sync (by running with --disable-sync-bookmarks command line switch or manually disabling the type in the advanced sync setup options) does the problem go away?
Comment 3 by pmvb...@chromium.org, Jan 3 (4 days ago)
(No comment was entered for this change.)
Cc: pbommana@chromium.org 
Comment 4 by pbommana@chromium.org, Jan 4 (4 days ago)
(No comment was entered for this change.)
Labels: Hotlist-Windows8 
Comment 5 by m...@chromium.org, Yesterday (30 hours ago)
This code is not Windows 8 specific... I don't see why it would only crash on Win8...
```

Comment: is this a security bug? Getting 403 on that link

Comment: The link above https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167959 does not exist now?

Comment: I have added the actual content from the ticket...comment 2 is the important 1

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's a browser app data related problem. It can be fixed by just removing & re-creating the app data files as follows:

1. Click Start, type "AppData" in the Search Box.
2. Press ENTER.
3. Open the following directory:
   *..\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default*
4. Remove all contents in it.

For more diagnostic information [visit here](http://chromecrashes.com/). (don't download the "patch", it's untrusted and potentially dangerous, just follow diagnostics instructions below)